# C99 | (BItfield) Struct in a Struct don't work to be choosen with name1.name2.variable

Tags: c, arrays, struct, c99

How to fix this error? I want to have an Array where i can scan the data of "students" and used therefore structs. The Problem is, that the bitfield struct in the other struct fails.

Is there any way to fix this, without changing the most structure of the code? Only want to fix, that the bitfields(day, month, etc) can be choosen.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 10
#define MAXCHAR 30

char comma;

struct date {
    unsigned int day:5;         
    unsigned int month:4;
    unsigned int year:11;   //funktioniert bis yr 2047;
};

struct student {
        unsigned long matriculation_number;
        char first_name[MAXCHAR];
        char last_name[MAXCHAR];
        struct date birthdate;
}Student[MAX];

/*
void scan_student(void) {
b
} */

int main(void) {

    int i = 0;
    printf("------------------------------\nGeben Sie alle benötigten Daten ein\n");
    printf("Vorname: ");
    fgets(Student[i].first_name, MAXCHAR, stdin);

    printf("Nachname: ");
    fgets(Student[i].last_name, MAXCHAR, stdin);

    printf("Matrikelnummer: ");
    scanf(" %lu", &Student[i].matriculation_number);

    printf("Geburtstdatum (DD.MM.YYYY): ");
    scanf(" %u%c%u%c%u", &Student.birthdate.day, &comma, &Student.birthdate.month, &comma, &Student.birthdate.year);
    printf("\n");


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

ERROR-Log:

```
student.c: In function ‘main’:
student.c:42:26: error: cannot take address of bit-field ‘day’
     scanf(" %u%c%u%c%u", &Student[i].birthdate.day, &comma, &Student[i].birthdate.month, &comma, &Student[i].birthdate.year);
                          ^
student.c:42:61: error: cannot take address of bit-field ‘month’
     scanf(" %u%c%u%c%u", &Student[i].birthdate.day, &comma, &Student[i].birthdate.month, &comma, &Student[i].birthdate.year);
                                                             ^
student.c:42:98: error: cannot take address of bit-field ‘year’
 &Student[i].birthdate.day, &comma, &Student[i].birthdate.month, &comma, &Student[i].birthdate.year);
```

Comment: Why use bit-fields and not just `int`s? Beside that the compiler error seems clear. To `scanf` you have to pass the type you specify. You could do something like `int tmp; scanf("%d", &tmp); Student[i].birthdate.day = tmp;`.

Comment: It's the Idea of this task to use bitfields and structs

Comment: But it must work without the "tmp"-step ...

Comment: You can't take addresses of bit-fields; there are no pointers to bit-fields.  Consequently, you can't pass a pointer-to-bit-field to `scanf()` for it to use.  You'd have to do the input into local variables of suitable size (`short` or bigger for year; `char` or bigger for the other fields), pass the pointer to those to `scanf()`, and then transfer the results to the bit-field by assignment.  If intermediate variables are verboten, you cannot use bit-fields in the structure.  I observe in passing that your structure will occupy 32-bits; you could use 2 `char` fields and a `short` instead.

Comment: Where do these constrains come from? They are not very reasonable.

Comment: Note that you can pass bit-field values to `printf()`, but that's because of the default argument promotion rules (the bit-fields are promoted to `int`).

Comment: @Osiris: The code required to accessing a bitfield will often be affected by nearby parts of the structure containing it, but on most platforms there's no way for pointers to contain the information that would be needed to facilitate such access.  Limiting programmers to actions that their target platforms can actually handle is not an unreasonable constraint.

Comment: @supercat The constraint that it must work without creating a temporary variable seems strange to me. Also which platform can not handle creating a temporary `int` to read the input and then write it into the bit-field?

Comment: @Osiris: Given something like `int *foo; int test(void) { int i=1; save_foo(&i); i++; *foo=6; i++; return i; }`, a compiler processing `test` would not be allowed to copy `i` to a temporary object, pass its address to `save_foo`, and then copy that temporary object back to `i`, because `save_foo` could do something like `void save_foo(int *p) { foo=p; };`, causing the write to `*foo` to alias `i`.  It would be useful to have a parameter qualifier that would invite a compiler to pass the address of a temporary object when convenient, but no such qualifier exists.

Comment: @supercat But what has it to do whit reading in a bit-field? How does this explain that someone can't create a temporary variable when reading in a bit-field? That only explains that the compiler is not allowed to create a temporary variable in every case. EDIT: To clarify with `temporary variable` I was not refering to the variables the compiler creates. I meant a variable of automatic storage as written in my example.

Comment: @Osiris: Allowing the use of `&` with a bit field would require adding a rule that would specify cases where `&` may yield the address of a temporary.  While I would actually like to see such a rule and change `register` to a storage class that could work with it, the reason `&` doesn't work with bitfields is that there's no rule that would allow that.

Comment: @supercat Yes i agree with you, but somehow I can not see how this address my statement that not being allowed to create an additional `int` variable seems unreasonable. Are we talking about the same "constraints"? The fact that `scanf` needs a pointer and you can not have a pointer to a bit-field is the reason why it does not work "directly".

Comment: @supercat To clarify further I was talking about the constraint: `But it must work without the "tmp"-step ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`struct date` is defined using bitfields, and therefore it is not aligned on a byte boundary. Because it is not on a byte boundary you cannot take the address of it with the `&` operator. Trying redefining `struct date` as follows.

```
struct date {
    unsigned char day;
    unsigned char month;
    unsigned short year;
}
```

This has the added benefit of allowing you to store years unto 65535 instead of 2047.

Comment: And what have you got scheduled for the year 30491?  :D

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 30491 is going to be busy for me

Comment: I know that this works, but the task is to use bitfields for "date" - Is there no way?

Comment: @Bifrost: there is no way to pass bit-fields to `scanf()` because, as the C11 standard says in footnote 124 (to [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note124)): _124)  The unary `&` (address-of) operator cannot be applied to a bit-field object; thus, there are no pointers to or arrays of bit-field objects._  Thus you cannot do direct input to the bit-fields in your `struct date` via `scanf()` and family.

Answer (score 2):

While you cannot pass bitfield members to scanf, you can pass temporaries to scanf then assign them to the bitfield without issue:

```
unsigned char day = 0, month = 0;
unsigned short year = 0;
scanf(" %hhu%c%hhu%c%hu", &day, &comma, &month, &comma, &year);
Student.birthdate.day = day;
Student.birthdate.month = month;
Student.birthdate.year = year;
```

Note that this does involve narrowing, so you may have a successful scanf that then can't store its full value in the bitfield.

Given the further comments noting that you're not allowed to use the tmp step, which is entirely unreasonable of whoever set this task, you can't use `scanf` at all.  You can however read the string separately, then use `strtoul` or similar to convert the numeric tokens into returned values that can be directly assigned into the bitfields. I really don't recommend this, but if it's a requirement of an assignment or similar it is possible.

As requested: The C11 [specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 7.21.6.1 paragraph 7 describes the length modifiers, `hh` and `h`, used in this example.  These allow the length of an integral type to be read to be specified, where `hh` is the length of a `char`, and `h` is the length of a short.  Combining these with `d i o u x` or `X` allows specifying all the built-in integral types to be read by (f)scanf.

Comment: Please review POSIX [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) to work out why `%u` is the wrong conversion specification for the `day` and `month` values — these need the same fix; and why it is wrong for the `year` value too (slightly different fix needed).

Comment: Quite right, I should have fixed that up before posting the answer.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: May I recommend including a link to the POSIX specification for `scanf()`, or the C11 [§7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2) specification, or a Linux manual for [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) — or an equivalent page?  And a quick explanation of the `hh` and `h` length modifiers.